# What is the difference between an Estimator and a Regressor in TensorFlow tf.estimator?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-estimator

TensorFlow Estimators ([tf.estimator](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator)) are "high level tools for working with models". Instead of defining your own DNN classifier layer by layer there is already an [estimator for that](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/DNNClassifier).

Everyone knows the difference between classifying features with a label and estimating a numeric value. However, what is the difference between a Regressor and an Estimator? For example DNNEstimator and DNNRegressor. The description says

> DNNEstimator - An estimator for TensorFlow DNN models with user-specified head.
>
> DNNRegressor - A regressor for TensorFlow DNN models.

A "head" in turn is an "interface for the head/top of a model". Would it be fair to say that DNNRegressor is a DNNEstimator with a RegressionHead or what is an Estimator?